# How is innovation measured in private-public partnerships?

Tags: economy, science

It is great that governments invest in innovation and research.

Specifically in research done by private public partnerships, they do a lot of controlling to track budget, but how do they measure the actual innovation after a next one PPP consuming 100 millions or more ends? (side but more fundamental question - is it actually possible to measure innovation?)

Comment: Can you clarify your question? "Research" covers a lot of ground. Do you mean scientific research, humanities research, political research, the research and development of new products or something else? "Innovation" also covers a lot of ground.  What sort of PPP are you thinking of? Most PPP is to do a specific job such as build and run a hospital, but it sounds like you are thinking of something else. Do you have any examples where research and innovation are the explicit goals of PPP? Or are you thinking of the rhetoric that says private involvement leads to increased innovation generally?

Comment: Also your question about measuring innovation is, as you say, more fundamental. Perhaps you should make it the central point of your question?

Comment: I have edited the title to better reflect the content (based on Paul Johnson's comments). Also I have expended the acronym as [it might not be clear for anyone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PPP).

Answer (score 1):

There are a few metrics I can think of, though without more specifics from the question it's hard to know which particular programs to check.

Patents granted, papers published, conference presentation - the standard ways of measuring academic progress would apply.

In terms of just measuring whether the projects are *successful* there are a few papers out there - this might be useful: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/320762746/download

> In general, a public-private partnership scheme can be described as successful if it offer greater value-for-money, provide
>   adequate financial return to the private investor (Ng et al. 2010), cost savings (Hambros 1999), reduction in construction time,
>   maintaining a high level of service quality (Akintoye et al. 2003) and satisfying the stakeholders (Leung et al. 2004; Udayangani
>   et al. 2011).

Comment: But are these metrics actually used in the real world by governments? Your answer would be much stronger if you would find some source which says which metrics are actually agreed upon in real-world public-private partnership contracts.